# warning message for pointer assignment two dimensional array pointer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, types

I wrote a program to read array elements at run time, where it then changes the column based on some configuration.

I get the following warning message from GCC cygwin compiler:

```
pointer.c:73: error: incompatible types in assignment
```

Considering the code below, how can I remove this warning?

Thank you in advance for your help

```
typedef struct INPUT_ST
{
    float a;
    float b;
    float c;
}INPUT;
const INPUT lookup[3][3];
main()
{
    INPUT *ptr;
    /*typedef INPUT (st[3][3]);*/
    INPUT (*ptr1)[3][3];
    int i, j;
    ptr = (INPUT *)&lookup;
    (*ptr1)[3][3] = &lookup[0][0];

    for(i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<3; j++)
        {
            printf("Row %d and column %d:\n", i, j);
            printf("%f\n", (*ptr1)[i][j].a);
            printf("%f\n", (*ptr1)[i][j].b);
            printf("%f\n\n", (*ptr1)[i][j].c);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: I would start by telling what's on line 73.

Comment: It's line 15 in the example code provided.

Answer (score 1):

The line causing the error is the following:

```
(*ptr1)[3][3] = &lookup[0][0];
```

The reason is that the left-hand-side and right-hand-sides of the assignment have incompatible types.

`ptr1` on the left is of type `INPUT (*)[3][3]` (a pointer to a 3x3 array of `INPUT`). `(*ptr1)[3][3]` is of type `INPUT` (dereferencing the (uninitialized) pointer and then accessing the (out-of-bounds) element `[3][3]`). `lookup` on the right is of type `const INPUT [3][3]` (3x3 array of `const INPUT`). That makes `&lookup[0][0]` to be of type `const INPUT *` (the address of the element `[0][0]`). So the types are conflicting: `INPUT` vs. `const INPUT *`.

What you are really trying to do is to make the `ptr1` pointer point to the array `lookup`. So you need to add `const` to the pointer declaration and then initialize it as follows:

```
const INPUT (*ptr1)[3][3];
// ...
ptr1 = &lookup;
```

The partial solution you have with `ptr` doesn't work because it is a regular pointer (single dimension), so you cannot access `ptr[i][j]`, that would mean to dereference `INPUT` which is not a pointer (but you *could* access `ptr[i*3+j]` instead of `ptr[i][j]`). By the way, instead of casting away the `const` as you do for `ptr` you should really declare `ptr` as `const INPUT *ptr;`.